# Plastic container within wooden frame-raised bed over concrete slabs

Tags: raised-beds

I need to create a raised bed garden mostly to propagate plants. I have an area covered in sun for most of the day. I need to propagate some bushes and decorative grasses and this will also be an area where I keep the plants till I decide on their position and use in my backyard garden (long term project)
The area adjacent to the garage is paved with large and cheap rectangular slabs. The raised bed will look like below and I don't know if I can use plastic containers like below for my project. I need to do that because I will get all the soil for the two raised beds later. For now I need to move some grasses and small plants so I can build the layout of my garden. In time I will build the wooden frame for the raised bed and add more containers and soil so I can propagate the grasses

Is the below o good idea? Do you foresee any problems with this?

[image]

Comment: Can you be clearer about which plants you want to propagate, and by 'propagate' do you simply mean 'splitting', or do you mean hard or soft cuttings, root cuttings and so on?

Comment: it might mean both, depends on the plant I guess. For grasses it is splitting as far as I understand

Comment: I'm not sure those planting boxes are the best solution for taking cuttings - softwood ones done around May either need to be in a greenhouse, or in a relatively shady corner of the garden with a lid or sheet of plastic. Hardwood cuttings are usually just inserted into rows in the ground and left there for up to 2 years. Other cuttings might be left in pots in a coldframe over winter, rather than out in the open.  The box system you've suggested would work for  perennials/grasses you split  though.

Comment: yes it will be for perrenials and grasses I do not intend to propagate trees ..bushes maybe

Comment: 'bushes' means shrubs, and shrubs are usually propagated either from soft or hardwood cuttings too. If you're going to use plastic boxes, they must have drainage holes in the bottom - no reason otherwise why you shouldn't use plastic containers, but full sun might be an issue for newly split plants.

Comment: There are some corner spots where I can put those less tolerant to sun. This will be parallel to a regular fence oriented North-South with another fence segment perpendicular on it at the south end so the south east corner of the geometry has partial sun in the afternoon. I think nursery is too much said...it will be a buffer area where I store my plants for an year or two before I decide where I put them